How to ensure that a voting rule that deals with alternative sets of different size always keeps the same logic?
I am working on a social choice problem that must allow for alternative sets of different sizes. In the paper I'm struggling to write, the environment is a $5$-tuple $(N,A_\tau,\mathcal{P}(A_\tau),\Delta(A_\tau),\sigma)$. First, $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$ is a finite voter set, where $n\geqslant2$. Second, $A_\tau=\{a_1,\dots,a_\tau\}$ is a finite alternative set, where $\tau\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dots\}$. Third,
\begin{gather}
    \mathcal{P}(A_\tau)=\bigl\{P\mid P=(P_i)_{i\in N}:P_i\text{ is voter $i$'s strict order over }A_\tau\bigr\}
\end{gather}
is the set of all strict preference profiles over some alternative set: namely, for all alternatives $x,y\in A_\tau$ and all voters $i\in N$, $x P_iy$ if and only if voter $i$ strictly prefers $x$ over $y$. Fourth,
\begin{gather}
    \Delta(A_\tau)=\left\{\delta\in[0,1]^{A_\tau}\mid\sum_{x\in A_\tau}\delta(x)=1\right\}
\end{gather}
is the set of all lotteries over some alternative set. And fifth,
\begin{gather}
    \sigma:\bigcup_{\tau\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{P}(A_\tau)\to\bigcup_{\tau\in\mathbb{N}}\Delta(A_\tau)    
\end{gather}
is a voting rule that satisfies $\sigma(P)\in\Delta(A_\tau)$ for all numbers $\tau\in\mathbb{N}$ and all strict preference profiles $P\in\mathcal{P}(A_\tau)$.
The problem that I face is that this definition of a voting rule allows for some funny objects which I would like to rule out. These funny objects are voting rules that change their logic depending on the size of the alternative set. To see so, construct a voting rule as follows:

If $\tau\leqslant3$ (i.e., there are at most three alternatives), our voting rule assigns identical weight to all alternatives that are top-ranked by the largest number of voters and null weight to all other alternatives (i.e., plurality rule);
If $\tau\geqslant4$ (i.e., there are four or more alternatives), our voting rule assigns weight one to the alternative that is top-ranked by voter $1$ (i.e., dictatorship of voter $1$).

I consider a voting rule like the one described above as funny because it changes its logic (or operation) depending on the size of the alternative set. My goal is to define an axiom that ensures that a voting rules does not change its logic (or operation) depending on the size of the alternative set, like the one described above.
Can anybody help me figure out how to change my definition of a voting rule to ensure that a voting rule does not change its logic depending on the size of the alternative set?
THINGS I HAVE TRIED: My field of expertise (if any) is quite far from abstract algebra and category theory, but I somehow feel that the solution to my problem lays in either of these two fields.

Following Qiaochu Yuan’s first comment to this related question, I have tried to rely on the notion of a natural transformation to define the axiom I need, but I haven’t succeeded.

Following Qiaochu Yuan’s accepted answer to this related question, I have tried to use the axiom he proposes, but it does not get me what I need.

I have also tried to use the notion of an homomorphism to define the axiom that I need, but I haven’t succeeded.


ADDITIONAL INFO: In case it helps, you can assume that the voting rule is anonymous and neutral, since an anonymous and neutral voting rule is simply a function of the number of times each voter $i\in N$ places each alternative in $m^{th}$ position in their preference $P_i$. Thus, the problem might be simpler under the anonymity and neutrality assumptions.
In order to define the axiom of anonymity, let $\Pi=\{\pi\in N^N\mid\pi\text{ is bijective}\}$ be the set of all permutations of the voter set. Then, given any number $\tau\in\mathbb{N}$, any profile $P\in\mathscr{P}(A_\tau)$ and any permutation $\pi\in\Pi$, let the profile $\pi P=(P_{\pi(i)})_{i\in N}\in\mathscr{P}(A_\tau)$ satisfy, for all voters $i\in N$ and all alternatives $x,y\in A_\tau$, $x\pi P_iy$ if and only if $xP_{\pi(i)}y$.

A voting rule is neutral if and only if it is independent of alternatives’ labels. Formally, if and only if
\begin{equation}
    (\forall\tau\in\mathbb{N})(\forall P\in\mathscr{P}(A_\tau))(\forall\pi\in\Pi)[\sigma(P)=\sigma(\pi P)]
\end{equation}

In order to define the axiom of neutrality, fix any number $\tau\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $M_\tau=\{\mu_\tau\in (A_\tau)^{A_\tau}\mid\mu_\tau\text{ is bijective}\}$ be the set of all permutations of the alternative set. Then, given any profile $P\in\mathscr{P}(A_\tau)$ and any permutation $\mu_\tau\in M_\tau$, let the profile $\mu_\tau P\in\mathscr{P}(A_\tau)$ satisfy, for all voters $i\in N$ and all alternatives $x,y\in A_\tau$, $\mu_\tau(x)\mu_\tau P_i\mu_\tau(y)$ if and only if $x P_iy$.

A voting rule is anonymous if and only if it is independent of voters’ names. Formally, if and only if
\begin{equation}
    (\forall\tau\in\mathbb{N})(\forall P\in\mathscr{P}(A_\tau))(\forall\mu_\tau\in M_\tau)(\forall x\in A_\tau)[(\sigma(P))(x)=(\sigma(\mu_\tau P))(\mu_\tau(x))]
\end{equation}

